# how to set customer of one store should not be able to login to another store in magento in single website

Tags: magento, authentication, store

I am using latest magento 1.7.0.2.
I have two different stores in my site.
customer from first store should not be able to login    to second store.
So,Want to set up store wise login for customers.How to set ?please help.

Comment: If there are 2 store views in the same website, you can't. Turn them in 2 separate websites and you can do it from System->Configuration->Customer configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Magento only allows you to set "customer sharing" across the global and website scopes. The (maybe not so simple) solution would be to move your other store to a separate website instead of a separate store.

Found in *System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration*:

[image: Found in System > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration]

Comment: But I can't change from store to website.Because I want both sore share same inventory for products.

Comment: Having separate websites should still let you share inventory between stores.